# Learning resource for 3d modeling

Tags: 3d, animation, blender, 3dsmax, maya

I want to start learning 3d modeling. I already have experience with maya and 3dsmax but I made a long pause (2 years)

Now I have free access to maya, 3dsmax and blender (I am a student). I know that all tools are very powerful so I thought I just pick the one with the best learning materials.

The best site that I found is http://www.digitaltutors.com/11/index.php and it has over 7600 videos for maya.

Maybe you can recommend me some other learning sites that are as good as digitaltutors?

Comment: I can't imagine how you'd be able to select a "correct" answer from the answers you're going to get here. You're just asking for a list of resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been learning how to use Blender on CGcookie, that is why I will recommend you the page - http://cgcookie.com/

It gives you tutorials on 3DS MAX and Blender which is similar to Maya (there is a Maya Mode), and its definitely worth getting the premium access (I learned a lot there). + its only ~ $30 for 90 days

I am not saying that open source is always better (its definitely cheaper) but in your situation I'd also give Blender a try, you will probably love it!

On the website. They have many videos + resources (models from the tutorial, textures etc.)

I'd also suggest that you visit the official Autodesk tutorial page

http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?siteID=123112&id=16759124&linkID=9241175

And definitely go to one of these :)

http://cgcookie.com/blender/

http://cgcookie.com/max/

Goog luck in your training!

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend http://www.3dbuzz.com
They have videos for many skill levels, though if you have an advanced level of skill with it already some of them will be pointless. Most videos require a membership but the introduction to Maya series is free in its entirety. Ive worked through some of them my self, and have watched some of their other videos on other topic and really enjoy the site as a whole.